# Current date alias as string in bash

Tags: bash, date, alias

I would like to create the current date as an alias called **now** in bash. I have tried adding the following to bashrc

**alias now="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"**

It seems to work, but doesn't quite. I am using it to call the program airflow which requires a time argument.
I usually write

**airflow test program 2021-05-07**

which gives the desired behavior.
However, if I write

**airflow test program now**

It interprets **now** as not only a date but as a timestamp with hours, minutes, and seconds which gives a different behavior. If I write **$now** instead, it works, but I would like **now** (without dollarsign) to simply be the string representation of todays date.

Comment: `It interprets now as not only a date but as a timestamp with hours, minutes, and seconds which gives a different behavior` That's not how alias works and it has _nothing_ to do with an alias. If you want a command `airflow` to interpret it's arguments differently, you should change that command.

Comment: But surely it is possible to make a alias which is todays date as a string without hours minutes and seconds. I don't want airflow to interprety its arguments differently (it works if I type 2021-05-07 so I just want it to work with an alias for todays date).

Answer (score 2):

> **It interprets** ...

So you should change **it**, because it is **it** that interprets it.

"It" here refers to airflow. You could mock the command and implement custom semantics or get airflow sources and patch the source and recompile and reinstall to implement custom semantics. A mock in a form of a bash function could look like the following:

```
airflow() {
    if [[ "$1" = test && "$2" = program && "$3" == now ]]; then
        command airflow test program "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
    else
        command airflow "$@"
    fi
}
```

Text in shell undergoes expansions - but expansions are triggered by special syntax, like `$var` causes variable expansion - `now` is not anyhow special and it's just the text `now`. Aliases affect the command name (the first word) of the command and not arguments*. Research what is an alias and when it's used, what are shell expansions and when they happen.

* Ok, aliases ending with a space trigger alias expansion on the next argument. So you could, potentially do something very very tricky like the following that requires 4 aliases to trigger the expansion on the 4th word:

```
$ alias airflow='airflow '
$ alias test='test '
$ alias program='program '
$ alias now='$(date +%Y-%m-%d)'
$ airflow test program now
```

because an alias ending with a space triggers alias expansion on the next word. But this seems to be counterintuitive for me and may cause havoc when `now` is randomly getting replaced by current date.

Comment: The bash function was really helpful and I could use to to solve my problem. Thanks a lot. I still would expect it to be possible using an alias, but using a function works even better and is a bit easier to customise for other needs.

Comment: The ~20 year old advice is: don't use alias, use a function.